# Is it correct to say: "we are not allowed pets in the flat"?

Tags: spoken-english

In BBC's The Flatmates program, a [dialogue](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode08/) goes like:

> We are not allowed pets in the flat.

Is it appropriate to drop "to keep" after "allowed"?

Comment: If you want to drop it, you can rephrase it as *pets are not allowed in the flat.*

Comment: @Ustanak right. Just wondering if that particular way of dropping (in BBC's) is some popular collocation used by native speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We are not allowed pets in the flat.
>   We are not allowed **to keep** pets in the flat.
>   We are not allowed **to have** pets in the flat.

These sentences are correct and have the same meaning to express pets being forbidden.

**To keep** / **to have** are implicit and understood.

Other ways of expressing might be

> Pets are not allowed *(in the flat)*.
>   We can't have pets.
>   Pets are forbidden.

Comment: can you give another example like this , that a native speaker would use in everyday conversation?

Answer (score 1):

The original quoted sentence is not North American idiom. It's probably UK idiom, it may be idiomatic only in a subset of UK usage, as it sounds a bit posh to me. "We aren't allowed to to have pets" would be more usual in North America.

But it is certainly grammatical and correct to put a noun right after allowed. "Am I allowed a phone call?" It's just kind of formal.

Comment: The question is clearly referring to UK English, with an example from the BBC set in the UK. "... not North American idiom"?! "Probably UK idiom"?!